# Component looping over infinitely after updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update state under a promise. But the component is going over and over again infinitely until it max out the heap size. I don't know what I'm missing here.
This is my code

```
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone';
import File from './File'
import parser from 'subtitles-parser'

const baseStyle = {
  flex: 1,
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  alignItems: 'center',
  padding: '20px',
  borderWidth: 2,
  borderRadius: 2,
  borderColor: '#eeeeee',
  borderStyle: 'dashed',
  backgroundColor: '#fafafa',
  color: '#bdbdbd',
  outline: 'none',
  transition: 'border .24s ease-in-out'
};

const activeStyle = {
  borderColor: '#2196f3'
};

const acceptStyle = {
  borderColor: '#00e676'
};

const rejectStyle = {
  borderColor: '#ff1744'
};

function Drag(props) {
  const {
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps,
    isDragActive,
    isDragAccept,
    isDragReject,
    acceptedFiles
  } = useDropzone();

  const style = useMemo(() => ({
    ...baseStyle,
    ...(isDragActive ? activeStyle : {}),
    ...(isDragAccept ? acceptStyle : {}),
    ...(isDragReject ? rejectStyle : {})
  }), [
    isDragActive,
    isDragReject
  ]);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  if(acceptedFiles.length === 1){
    const  readUploadedFileAsText = (acceptedFiles) => {
      const temporaryFileReader = new FileReader();      
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        temporaryFileReader.onerror = () => {
          temporaryFileReader.abort();
          reject(new DOMException("Problem parsing input file."));
        };

        temporaryFileReader.onload = () => {
          resolve(parser.fromSrt(temporaryFileReader.result));
        };
        temporaryFileReader.readAsText(acceptedFiles);
      });
    };
    let file = acceptedFiles[0]
    readUploadedFileAsText(file)
    .then(res => {
      setData({
        data: res
      })
    })
  } 

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div {...getRootProps({style})}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
      </div>      
      <File file={data} />      
      {console.log(data)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Drag
```

Let me know if I have to use any lifecycle methods. I tried using componentDidMount and componentWillReceiveProps but both didn't work for me or I hadn't done them in right way.

Comment: Why are you having a function `readUploadedFileAsText` in your component stand alone inside a `if` condition?

Comment: You are calling readUploadedFileAsText on component render, which thens with a new state, which again causes the component to rerender, creating an infinite loop

Comment: And you are calling `readUploadedFileAsText(file)` afterwards... the syntax looks so wrong, are they supposed to be wrapped in a `onDrop` function of your `dropzone` (which doesn't seem exist) that you mistakenly delete?

Comment: I'm checking for the file object. In the initial render there will be no data in the acceptedFiles object. If the file object isn't null I want to convert the file and update the content to state so that I can send that to another component as props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your **readUploadedFileAsText** function outside of the if statement it is in. Then you can add your if and function call to **React.useEffect** which will call the function on initial load, but not on every subsequent re-render.

```
function Drag(props) {
    const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive, isDragAccept, isDragReject, acceptedFiles } = useDropzone();

    const style = useMemo(
        () => ({
            ...baseStyle,
            ...(isDragActive ? activeStyle : {}),
            ...(isDragAccept ? acceptStyle : {}),
            ...(isDragReject ? rejectStyle : {})
        }),
        [isDragActive, isDragReject]
    );
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    const readUploadedFileAsText = acceptedFiles => {
        const temporaryFileReader = new FileReader();
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            temporaryFileReader.onerror = () => {
                temporaryFileReader.abort();
                reject(new DOMException('Problem parsing input file.'));
            };

            temporaryFileReader.onload = () => {
                resolve(parser.fromSrt(temporaryFileReader.result));
            };
            temporaryFileReader.readAsText(acceptedFiles);
        });
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (acceptedFiles.length === 1) {
            let file = acceptedFiles[0];
            readUploadedFileAsText(file).then(res => {
                setData({
                    data: res
                });
            });
        }
    }, [acceptedFiles]);


    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div {...getRootProps({ style })}>
                <input {...getInputProps()} />
                <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
            </div>
            <File file={data} />
            {console.log(data)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it's not working. Now the state is not updating at all.

Comment: Are you importing React at the top of your file? Are you getting any errors now? If possible a Sandbox environment with your code would be amazing so I can check further what's happening.

Comment: check out this sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-brown-fks3j?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Pls drag or select srt files. The parser works on srt files only.

Comment: Thank you. Implementing my answer seems to work for me. I did miss a dependency to useEffect but shouldn't have made a difference. Try this Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-jang-cid9q?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thank you. It works. Even I did the same thing but I didn't pass acceptedFiles as a callback to useEffect. Also, I'm getting the output more than once on the console. To be exact it is 3 times. If you can explain or atleast suggest some docs to understand this wierd behaviour would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. As for the output, it looks to be to do with the react-dropzone package. It's firing the state update on load, on click of the box, and on file upload. Hence 3 logs. There might be a better prop you can use to only update in successful upload